# Angular with Okta Deployed in IIS

Tags: angular, okta

I have an Angular 8 application with Okta. I have a WEb Api I'm deploying the Angular 8 application into the wwwroot folder. I'm deploying the application to IIS. I can run the application locally but it fails when I deploy. I'm assuming I have to use the URL Rewrite module in IIS but I can't seem to get the routing figured out if that's the problem.

Error:
page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://mysite/implicit/callback#id_token=

Angular route:
{ path: "",  component: ProfessionalLocalUserComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], data: { onAuthRequired } },
  { path: "professionallocal", component: ProfessionalLocalUserComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], data: { onAuthRequired } },
  { path: "professionalglobal", component: ProfessionalGlobalUserComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], data: { onAuthRequired } },
  { path: "adminglobal", component: AdminGlobalUserComponent, canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard], data: { onAuthRequired } },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  { path: "implicit/callback", component: OktaCallbackComponent },

The index.html for the Angular application is located in a folder named wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 8 uses HTML5's history mode by default, which means you have to configure your web server to send all 404s to index.html. This tutorial looks like it'll help to configure IIS:

https://gingter.org/2017/03/20/deep-link-angular-spa-iis/

Answer (score 0):

While configuring Okta add "cookies: { sameSite: 'lax', secure: false }" and it will work.